# Assigning to new Excel file with array value

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA script is basically to convert our company format from 3rd party.
What I have done so far, I convert data and store string array. now I want to open new excel file and store string array. How can I assign to new excel file with my array? I really appreciated if anyone could help me out.

Thanks

```
    Sub Convert()

    Dim cell As Range

    Dim sCode As String      'Securtiy code
    Dim symbol As String     'Symbol
    Dim receiveDate As Date  'Date
    Dim bidNum As Double    'Bid
    Dim askNum As Double    'Ask
    Dim closeNum As Double  'Close
    Dim sDesc As String      'Security Desc
    Dim cusip As String      'Cusip
    Dim cur As String        'Currency
    Dim pFactor As String    'Principal Factor


    Dim result As String     'Final result

    delim = "++^||"

    NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    Dim arrResult() As Variant
    ReDim arrResult(Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count)

    Range("A2").Select
    c = 2

    For x = 1 To NumRows

        '============ c is row ==========

        sCode = Cells(c, 1)
        symbol = Cells(c, 2)
        receiveDate = Cells(c, 3)
        bidNum = Cells(c, 4)
        askNum = Cells(c, 5)
        closeNum = Cells(c, 6)
        sDesc = Cells(c, 7)
        cusip = Cells(c, 8)
        cur = Cells(c, 9)
        pFactor = Cells(c, 10)

        c = c + 1

        result = storeFun(sCode, symbol, receiveDate, bidNum, askNum, closeNum, sDesc, cusip, cur, pFactor)
        arrResult(x - 1) = result

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Next

cell(12, 1) = arrResult(2)

End Sub

Function storeFun(sCode, symbol, receiveDate, bidNum, askNum, closeNum, sDesc, cusip, cur, pFactor) As String

Dim strDate As String
Dim strbidNum As String
Dim straskNum As String
Dim strcloseNum As String
Dim delim As String      '"++^||"

strDate = Format(receiveDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
strbidNum = Format(bidNum, "00.00000000")
straskNum = Format(askNum, "00.00000000")
strcloseNum = Format(closeNum, "00.00000000")

delim = "++^||"
storeFun = sCode + delim + symbol + delim + strDate + delim + strbidNum + delim + straskNum + _
            delim + strcloseNum + delim + sDesc + delim + cusip + delim + cur + delim + pFactor + delim

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think you can do, pass your array in subroutine where you open the new workbook.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim a(10) As Variant
    For i = 0 To UBound(arry, 1)
        a(i) = i * 2
    Next

    ParseArray a
  End Sub


Public Sub ParseArray(arrValues() As Variant)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    For i = 0 To UBound(arrValues, 1)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1) = arrValues(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the entire array to a range(they have to match in size), but a 1 dimensional array is one row high by many columns, where 2+D arrays are row dependent.  This should write the transposed array as 1 column by as many rows that are in the array

```
Dim RNG As Range
Set RNG = ActiveWorkSheet.Range("A1")
Set RNG = Destination.Resize(UBound(arrResult), 1)
RNG.Value = Application.Transpose(arrResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that demonstrates creating an array, then assigning it to a new workbook.  You should be able to modify your code to make use of this

Note that the created array is 2D

- The first dimension represents the rows
- The Second dimension represents the columns

This created array is then passed to a second `Sub` which will add a new workbook (based on your default template, although you can change that)

- Note that the destination range is sized to be the same as the passed array
- Note that the array is written to the worksheet in a single step.

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateTestArray()
    Dim myArr() As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

ReDim myArr(1 To 10, 1 To 2)

For I = 1 To 10
    For J = 1 To 2
        myArr(I, J) = Int((999 - 100 + 1) * Rnd + 100)
    Next J
Next I

WriteToNewWB myArr    
End Sub

'-------------------------------------

Sub WriteToNewWB(arr)
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim R As Range

Set WB = Workbooks.Add

Set R = WB.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
Set R = R.Resize(rowsize:=UBound(arr, 1), columnsize:=UBound(arr, 2))

With R
    .Value = arr
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
End Sub
```